# What exactly negative/positive value of Captum's Integrated Gradient mean?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, data, pytorch

I use Captum's Integrated Gradient to interprete my PyTorch's neural network. I know that from github and original paper mentioned that ...

> Positive attribution score means that the input in that particular
> position positively contributed to the final prediction and negative
> means the opposite. The magnitude of the attribution score signifies
> the strength of the contribution. Zero attribution score means no
> contribution from that particular feature.

But what exactly positively/negatively contribution mean in human language ?
I have to explain these to my co-worker.

Does negative mean that value of feature have less informative to prediction of that class ?
When I average score of all values as graph below.
What exactly the most negative(or most positive) score mean in human language ?
[image]